# Katakana (potentially gibberish) "sentence" in Bibara Bibara: meaningful or not?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

In the middle of [Bibara Bibara by Stereopony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nukTlm4aSE8) (lyrics [here](http://en.verygooddays.com/stereopony/lyrics/viva-la-viva-la/)), there is this weird Katakana "sentence":

> ホートトトギスがホーホー

I cannot make any sense of it, but I do see a Hiragana syllable in the middle of Katakana, and it happens to be a particle, which makes me wonder: can this be made any sense of? Is this a meaningful sentence in Japanese? Are the sounds chosen for some reason, or is it just plain "scat"?

**Update**

I looked stuff up on JEDict and found the following. 蓬々{ほうほう} means "confusedly, perplexedly", and 方法{ほうほう} means "method", while 方途{ほうと} means "path". That is all I can see in there. Well, there is ホトトギス meaning "toad lily" or "cuckoo"… maybe "the toad lilies are confused" with a few extra syllables *because why not*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't gibberish.  In fact, there's even a clue at the beginning of the video; you can hear a cuckoo clock in the background.  ホトトギス is a cuckoo (a bird).  I presume that ホーホー is probably just the sound the bird makes.